# Mitzvos bein adam l'chavero vs. mitzvos bein adam l'makom

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, bein-adam-lachavero

I'm wondering if there are any early sources that discuss the relative importance of mitzvos bein adam l'chavero and mitzvos bein adam l'makom. Eg, if one is in a position to only do one or the other, or improve in one area or the other. Something from Gemara/Rishonim is preferable but notable achronim is also acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually we don't choose one over the other, I don't really know of a source that would maintain that one is better unless perhaps it accomplishes both somehow I suppose.

Comment: It depends. There are different rules for different cases. As for improvement in areas, it probably depends on the person.

Comment: The reason this area of *halachah* is unclear is because there are no *shiurim* for *bein adam le'chaveiro*. I.e. the *shiur* for *achilah* is a *kzayis*, but what is the *shiur* of *gaavah*? That is why the *baalei mussar* tried to express things in absolute terms, so you shouldn't get into a relativistic discussion.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, we learn from Avraham Avinu (in Beraishis 18) that “inviting guests is greater than greeting the Shechinah!”(Shabbos 127a)

With regards to Torah study, in a case where you are needed for a Mitzvah, one is obligated to interrupt his learning (Megillah 3b)

On the other hand, in general, Mitzvos between man and G-d take precedence, like it says (Bava Metzia 32a) regarding honoring parents, returning a lost item, assisting another man with his load etc.

Comment: The Gemara in BM sees honouring parents as only a positive against a positive and a negative. Assisting another man over the animal, I presume this is a disagreement about if it is a Torah law or Rabbinic, not whether it is a mitzvah to help a fellow vs a mitzvah by Hashem. Not sure about returning a lost item, didn't see it there... About the other proofs, Megilla 3b doesn't deal with the type of mitzvah? If all mitzvahs take precedence over Torah, then Torah is the reason, not because one type is more valuable. Greeting the Shechina is afaik not a mitzvah? What is the argument?

Comment: I apologize, but I don't see how these argue one mitzvah is more important then another....

Comment: There is no specific mitzvah to greet the shechina.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the bottom of Bava Metzia 30A that a Kohen who can return a lost object but will become tamei (impure), we do not say that we can override the negative commandment between the Kohen and Hashem (to not become impure) because he can return a lost object (between man and man). Now it does appear there that there is a positive and negative commandment to not become Tamei. Perhaps if it was only a negative commandment he would.

Nevertheless, the Meshech Chochma (Vayikra 19:4) says that one could not consider the idea that a mitzvah between man and his fellow could push off one between man and Hashem. Honouring your parents needed to be taught does not take precedence over Hashem because part of honouring your parents includes honouring Hashem, but still it cannot override.

The Chasam Sofer in Sucah 42A says that one could not consider overriding a mitzvah between man for Hashem, like stealing to do a mitzvah for Hashem. Only a negative against Hashem can be overridden by a positive Mitzvah for Hashem.

The Shav"T Shem Aryeh (in siman 64) explains that mitzvot between men contain also an element of man and Hashem since he commanded it, but man and Hashem don't contain an element of mitzvah between men. And so one is more categorically obvious to not push off the other.

In Summary, we saw with the Meshech Chochma and Chassam Sofer that only mitvahs of Bein Adam L'Makom can push be "traded", ie: a positive override a negative. So clearly a positive of one cannot override the negative of the other type.

What about two positive mitzvot?

We don't consider one "more important" than another. See Pirkei Avos 2:1 "And be [as] careful with a “light” Mitzvah as with a weighty one, for you don’t know the reward given for [each of the] Mitzvoth".

Usually when considering Mitzvahs there are a number of considerations like, the time limit of one mitzvah ending before another, if one occurs more often, or will one be a negative prohibition. There might be a few more, but I have not seen the idea that one should do mitzvah A over mitzvah B because it was one class or another.

In fact Rashi at the beginning of Parshat Mishpatim says that the monetary rules were given on Har Sinai like everything else, imo equating the mitzvot. Similarly the ten commandments were given together and even said at the [same time](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2896/jewish/What-Are-the-Ten-Commandments.htm), likely to show the equivalence of their status.